# How to disable GPU without bbswitch

Tags: nvidia, gpu, battery, optimus, hybrid-graphics

`BBswitch` is apparently dead with the last commit being 5 years ago and it no longer works with more modern kernels. During shutdown, it just hangs the system. `Nouveau` doesn't support power management on my GPU either.

I'd like to know what others are using who are in my situation as I don't need the nVidia GPU just running for no reason and would rather power it off when I'm on battery.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKasS7DWn0s

Comment: that youtube video suggests modifying grub with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="<whatever was there> acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\\\"Windows 2009\\\"" however I believe the best way to fully power down a GPU on pcie is to use **acpi_call**.  I am interested in this as well, but this is as far as i've gotten on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

With the `nouveau` driver, "power management" can mean several things.

On modern kernels, the `nouveau` driver knows how to access the same ACPI interface as `bbswitch`  does, and will present it using the `vgaswitcheroo`  mechanism, as `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` if you have the `debugfs` virtual filesystem mounted. This is essentially a solved problem: if you use the `nouveau` driver, you should no longer need `bbswitch`, period.

What the `nouveau` project usually means when talking about power management these days is monitoring the temperature of the GPU and adjusting its performance levels (clock speeds) dynamically. This is entirely separate from the power-off mechanism provided with `vgaswitcheroo`.

Comment: Here's a link to the page https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/PowerManagement/ and I have the NV160 it says "TODO" for everything under it. And vgaswitcharoo is apparently mainly made for hardware muxed devices. If it works with modern systems I'll try to use it.